# C# Controller isn't picking up nonsequential list items from the post content

Tags: c#, list, post, controller, integer

I'm using Umbraco's `SurfaceController`, which is based on a `Controller`. In the controller I have the following function:

```
public IActionResult HandleKitEdit([Bind(Prefix = "PostContent")] SMUKitPostViewModel postContent, string? returnUrl = null)
{
     ...
}
```

The `SMUKitPostViewModel` contains the following property:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<int>> JerseyLayers { get; set; }
```

With the current logic of the application, the data in the lists `List<int>` are loaded into the razor views like:

```
PostContent.JerseyLayers[Basic][0]: 1728
PostContent.JerseyLayers[Basic][1]: 1730
PostContent.JerseyLayers[Basic][2]: 1728
PostContent.JerseyLayers[Extra][0]: 1730
PostContent.JerseyLayers[Extra][1]: 1728
PostContent.JerseyLayers[Extra][2]: 1730
```

The front-end does however select some of these list items, so that only a few are being posted. For example:

```
PostContent.JerseyLayers[Basic][0]: 1728
PostContent.JerseyLayers[Basic][1]: 1730
PostContent.JerseyLayers[Basic][2]: 1728
PostContent.JerseyLayers[Extra][0]: 1730
PostContent.JerseyLayers[Extra][2]: 1730
```

Now, `PostContent.JerseyLayers[Extra][2]: 1730` isn't being picked up by the controller. Is it possible that this list with a non-sequential index can be picked up by the controller?

I've tried to convert the `List<int>` in the `Dictionary<string<List<int>>` to an `int[]`. This didn't seem to work.

I'm expecting five results (following the example above). I get four results in the post content, with `PostContent.JerseyLayers[Extra][2]: 1730` missing.